# Thread' not found when i install pthread

Tags: php

I try install threads on wampp(i use http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/0.0.44/php_pthreads-0.0.44-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip) throw this **Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found**

i follow this step
Extract the zip.
Move php_pthreads.dll to the php\ext\ directory.
Move pthreadVC2.dll to the php\ directory.

Open php\php.ini and add
extension=php_pthreads.dll

...,but thread class not found

my php build extension is vc9,
php-version is 5.4.12

Comment: have you restarted the server? and sometimes even restarting you computer would solve this

Comment: BTW upgrade your PHP too :P

Comment: Are you instantiating it?  What does that code look like?  Otherwise, "pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) enabled ( --enable-maintainer-zts or --enable-zts on Windows )"

Comment: When restart my PC problem does not solve

Comment: A just extends thread class

Comment: Where I can enable zts